# Invalid css style during zooming in calendar

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML code with event calendar.
The calendar looks as follows:  [calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVZI1.png)

I have some problem, because when I'm trying zooming this calendar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + scroll mouse, then with zooming there is a problem. For instance, with zooming 150% (and in other cases also) in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, there is an additional column with little width. This can be seen in the figure here:

[zooming calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMRYi.png)

```css
body {
  background-color: #789;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#content {
  display: block;
  width: 812px;
  margin: 40px auto 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
  box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
}

h2,
p {
  margin: 0 auto 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  height: 82px;
  width: 812px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 2px 2px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 110px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #FCB;
  z-index: 1;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
}

.weekdays {
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.weekdays li {
  height: 16px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  background-color: #BCF;
}

.fill {
  background-color: #BCD;
}

.weekdays li:hover,
li.fill:hover {
  background-color: #BCD;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.weekdays li:hover,
.today {
  background-color: #BCF;
}

li strong {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}

li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: #DEF;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #BCF;
  z-index: 2;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h2>January 2016</h2>
  <ul class="weekdays">
    <li>Sun
    </li>
    <li>Mon
    </li>
    <li>Tue
    </li>
    <li>Wed
    </li>
    <li>Thu
    </li>
    <li>Fri
    </li>
    <li>Sat
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;
    </li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;
    </li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;
    </li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;
    </li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>01</strong>
      <a href="view.php?event_id=1">New Year's Day</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>02</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      <strong>03</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>04</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>05</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>06</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>07</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>08</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>09</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      <strong>10</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>11</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>12</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>13</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>14</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>15</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>16</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      <strong>17</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>18</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>19</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>20</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>21</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>22</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>23</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      <strong>24</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>25</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>26</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>27</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>28</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>29</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <strong>30</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      <strong>31</strong>
      <a href="view.php?event_id=2">Last Day of January</a>
    </li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
  </ul>
```

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right code. Plugging that into JSFiddle gives me this. https://jsfiddle.net/rmu06m16/

Comment: Here is the right effect of code: https://jsfiddle.net/rmu06m16/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rmu06m16/3/ <--- corrected jsfiddle but indeed, even when plugging it into a html and css file on my local server doesn't have the problem you're having, and I also don't see the problem on your website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you check this...

```css
body {
 background-color: #789;
 font-family: georgia, serif;
 font-size: 13px;
}
#content {
 display: block;
 width: 812px;
 margin: 40px auto 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 border:2px solid black;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
 box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
}
h2, p {
 margin: 0 auto 14px;
 text-align: center;
}
ul {
 display: block;
 clear: left;
 height: 80px;
 width: 812px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-top: 0;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
li {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px 0px 0px;
 width: 14.28571428571429%;
 height: 60px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: white;
}
li:before {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 height:100%;
 width: 1px;
 background-color:#000;
}
li:after {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 height:100%;
 width: 1px;
 background-color:#000;
}
li:hover {
 background-color: #FCB;
 z-index: 1;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
}
.weekdays {
 height: 20px;
 border-top: 2px solid black;
}
.weekdays li {
 height: 20px;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #BCF;
 line-height:20px;
}
.fill {
 background-color: #BCD;
}
.weekdays li:hover, li.fill:hover {
 background-color: #BCD;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}
.weekdays li:hover, .today {
 background-color: #BCF;
}
li strong {
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 right: 2px;
}
li a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 border: 1px dotted black;
 margin: 2px;
 padding: 2px;
 font-size: 11px;
 background-color: #DEF;
 text-align: left;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 z-index: 1;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic;
}
li a:hover {
 background-color: #BCF;
 z-index: 2;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
 box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
}
```

```html
<ul class="weekdays">
  <li>Sun </li>
  <li>Mon </li>
  <li>Tue </li>
  <li>Wed </li>
  <li>Thu </li>
  <li>Fri </li>
  <li>Sat </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp; </li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp; </li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp; </li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp; </li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp; </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>01</strong> <a href="view.php?event_id=1">New Year's Day</a> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>02</strong> </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class=""> <strong>03</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>04</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>05</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>06</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>07</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>08</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>09</strong> </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class=""> <strong>10</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>11</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>12</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>13</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>14</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>15</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>16</strong> </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class=""> <strong>17</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>18</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>19</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>20</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>21</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>22</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>23</strong> </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class=""> <strong>24</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>25</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>26</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>27</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>28</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>29</strong> </li>
  <li class=""> <strong>30</strong> </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class=""> <strong>31</strong> <a href="view.php?event_id=2">Last Day of January</a> </li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still you are facing same issue?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your code is fine. Problem has disappeared ;) Could you tell me what you has changed in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

> https://jsfiddle.net/ds2zb4gv/

```css
background-color: #789;
font-family: georgia, serif;
font-size: 13px;
}

#content {
display: block;
/*width: 812px;*/
margin: 40px auto 10px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
border:2px solid black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
box-shadow: 0 0 14px #123;
}
h2,p {
margin: 0 auto 14px;
text-align: center;
}
ul {
display: block;
clear: left;
/*height: 82px;*/
width: 812px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
/*background-color: #FFF;*/
text-align: center;
/*border: 1px solid black;*/
/*border-top: 0;*/
/*border-bottom: 2px solid black;*/
}
li {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px 2px 2px;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
width: 110px;
height: 60px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
li:hover {
background-color: #FCB;
z-index: 1;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #789;
}
.weekdays {
/*height: 20px;*/
/*border-top: 2px solid black;*/
}
.weekdays li {
height: 16px;
padding: 2px 2px;
background-color: #BCF;
}
.fill {
background-color: #BCD;
}
.weekdays li:hover,li.fill:hover {
background-color: #BCD;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
.weekdays li:hover,.today {
background-color: #BCF;
}
li strong {
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
right: 2px;
}
li a {
position: relative;
display: block;
border: 1px dotted black;
margin: 2px;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 11px;
background-color: #DEF;
text-align: left;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
z-index: 1;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
}
li a:hover {
background-color: #BCF;
z-index: 2;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
box-shadow: 0 0 6px #789;
}
```

```html
<h2>January 2016</h2>
<ul class="weekdays">
<li>Sun
</li>
<li>Mon
</li>
<li>Tue
</li>
<li>Wed
</li>
<li>Thu
</li>
<li>Fri
</li>
<li>Sat
</li>
</ul><ul>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;
</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;
</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;
</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;
</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>01</strong>
    <a href="view.php?event_id=1">New Year's Day</a>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>02</strong>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="">
    <strong>03</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>04</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>05</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>06</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>07</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>08</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>09</strong>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="">
    <strong>10</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>11</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>12</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>13</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>14</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>15</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>16</strong>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="">
    <strong>17</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>18</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>19</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>20</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>21</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>22</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>23</strong>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="">
    <strong>24</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>25</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>26</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>27</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>28</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>29</strong>
</li>
<li class="">
    <strong>30</strong>
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li class="">
    <strong>31</strong>
    <a href="view.php?event_id=2">Last Day of January</a>
</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
<li class="fill">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div></code>
```